# Android Error: "Not a statement" with "Button"

Tags: android

I've been struggling with my code which is shows the error "Not a statement" on "Button" line

Here is my code:

```
public class NewShiftActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_shift);

        Button button = new (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                startActivity(new Intent(NewShiftActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
            }

        });
    }
}
```

I'm using Android Studio, API 23

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simply delete the `new` in the line `Button button = new (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);`

Comment: Just remove the keyword new from the statement `Button button = new (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply Remove the `new` keyword from Button

like:

```
 Button button =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
```